Unity. Photon PUN2. Waiting for photon.Rpc to complete
I'm creating a cooperative on Unity and I'm having a problem using remote calls. At the end of the game, the players send their data to the Master client to process it and determine the winner based on this, I send the data using photon.Rpc. And the problem is that remote calls work with a certain delay, which is logical, and I want to somehow determine when exactly the player will send the data, so that you can start processing it after that. I mean something about the asynchronous approach.
At the moment, I'm using the delay to wait for all the data to arrive, but I'm not completely satisfied with it. Thank you in advance!
